# Clicking label should select radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, nan

## Problem

I'm styling radio inputs on a Google Form, but clicking the label `.button__form` should select the actual `input[type="radio]` and add the class `is--selected` to the label. But if I don't click the actual circle the `totalAmount` doesn't get calculated, which is a problem.

**SOLVED** - Also an issue is that right now, the `totalAmount` of bids is coming up as `$Nan` instead of an actual number.

### scripts.js

```
    /*-------------------------------------
    STEP ONE: PLACE BID
    --------------------------------------*/

  $.ajax({
   url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/4a8eceba",
   method: "GET",
   dataType: "json"
 }).then(function(spreadsheet) {


  /*-------------------------------------
  SUM BIDS IN ARRAY
  --------------------------------------*/

  var arr = spreadsheet.result;
  var arrSum = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrSum += parseInt(arr[i].Bids);
  }

  // Print current bid
  // var currentBid = parseInt(spreadsheet.result.pop().Bids);
  var currentBid = arrSum;
  $(".current__amount").html("$" +currentBid);

  var baseAmount = 0;
  var totalAmount = baseAmount;
  var counterArray = [];

  $('.button__form').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).hasClass('is--selected')) {
      $(this).removeClass('is--selected');
      $(".check--one").css("color", "#ccc");
      $(".new__amount").css("margin-left", 10 + "px");
      $(".bids__dollar").addClass("is--hidden");
      totalAmount = parseInt(totalAmount) - parseInt(value);

      counterArray.forEach(function (count) {
        if (count && count.reset) {
          count.reset();
        }
      });

      $('.total__amount').text("---");

    } else {
      $(".button__form").removeClass('is--selected');
      $(this).addClass('is--selected');
      $(".check--one").css("color", "#ffdc00");
      totalAmount = currentBid; // Reset totalAmount to baseAmount
      totalAmount = parseInt(totalAmount) + parseInt(value);
      $('.total__amount').html("$" + totalAmount); // Problem line?
      $(".bids__dollar").removeClass("is--hidden");
      $(".new__amount").css("margin-left", 0 + "px");

      // CountUp
      $(function() {
        var options = {
            useEasing : true,
            useGrouping : true,
            separator : '',
            decimal : '',
            prefix : '',
            suffix : ''
        };
        var count = new CountUp("count", 0, totalAmount, 0, 1.5, options);
        count.start();
        counterArray.push(count);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

## index.html (Form snippet)

```
<section class="bids clearfix">
                    <div class="bids__info">
                        <div class="bids__step bids--one">
                            <h2>Step One</h2>
                            <div class="bids__checkmark">
                                <i class="fa fa-check check--one"></i>
                            </div>

                            <p class="bids__note">Pick one of the amounts below to add to the current bid.</p>

                            <!-- Form begins here -->
                            <form action="https://docs.google.com/a/andrewnguyen.ca/forms/d/1Dtw6KRUS-4y-C8DXB2d-CTHT_FOBrO9v_ZXZFC4oxxU/formResponse" method="POST">
                            <div class="buttons clearfix" name="entry.1455057699">
                                <ul class="ss-choices" role="radiogroup" aria-label="Bids"><li class="ss-choice-item"><label class="button__form button__one" for="group_1455057699_1"><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.1455057699" value="10" id="group_1455057699_1" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="10" required="" aria-required="true"></span>
                                <span class="ss-choice-label">$10</span>
                                </label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><label class="button__form button__two" for="group_1455057699_2"><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.1455057699" value="25" id="group_1455057699_2" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="25" required="" aria-required="true"></span>
                                <span class="ss-choice-label">$25</span>
                                </label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><label class="button__form button__three" for="group_1455057699_3"><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.1455057699" value="50" id="group_1455057699_3" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="50" required="" aria-required="true"></span>
                                <span class="ss-choice-label">$50</span>
                                </label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><label class="button__form button__four" for="group_1455057699_4"><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.1455057699" value="100" id="group_1455057699_4" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="100" required="" aria-required="true"></span>
                                <span class="ss-choice-label">$100</span>
                                </label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><label class="button__form button__five" for="group_1455057699_5"><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.1455057699" value="250" id="group_1455057699_5" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="250" required="" aria-required="true"></span>
                                <span class="ss-choice-label">$250</span>
                                </label></li> <li class="ss-choice-item"><label class="button__form button__six" for="group_1455057699_6"><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.1455057699" value="500" id="group_1455057699_6" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="500" required="" aria-required="true"></span>
                                <span class="ss-choice-label">$500</span>
                                </label></li></ul>
                            </div><!-- /.buttons -->

                            <div class="bids__amounts">
                                <div class="bids__amount bids__current">
                                    <p class="bids__note">The last bid was</p>
                                    <h4 class="current__amount">---</h4>
                                </div>

                                <div class="bids__amount bids__new">
                                    <p class="bids__note">Your bid will be</p>
                                    <h4 class="bids__dollar is--hidden">$</h4><h4 class="new__amount total__amount" id="count">---</h4>
                                </div><!-- /.bids__amount -->
                            </div><!-- /.bids__amounts -->
                        </div>


                        <div class="bids__step bids--two">
                            <h2 class="bids__form">Step Two</h2>
                            <div class="bids__checkmark">
                                <i class="fa fa-check check--two"></i>
                            </div>
                            <p class="bids__note bids__warning">Fill out the form below. Fields with an asterisk <span class="form__asterisk">(*)</span> are mandatory.

                                <fieldset class="form__wrapper">
                                    <div class="input__row">
                                        <legend>Full Name</legend>
                                        <label for="first-name">Full Name <span class="form__asterisk">*</span></label>
                                        <input class="input__full" id="first-name" name="entry.993143629" type="text" required="" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">

                                        <legend>Address*</legend>
                                        <label for="mailing-address-1">Address <span class="form__asterisk">*</span></label>
                                        <input class="input__address" class="form__mailing" id="mailing-address-1" name="entry.703646201" type="text" required="" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input__row">
                                        <div class="input__group input--half input__group--city">
                                            <label for="city">City <span class="form__asterisk">*</span></label>
                                            <input class="input__city" id="city" name="entry.250562623" type="text" placeholder="Brandon" required="" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="input__group input--quarter input__group--province">
                                            <label for="province">Province <span class="form__asterisk">*</span></label>
                                            <select name="entry.1321194614" class="input__province" aria-label="Province  " aria-required="true" required=""><option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="" disabled> - Provinces - </option>
                                                <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
                                                <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
                                                <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
                                                <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
                                                <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                                                <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
                                                <option value="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
                                                <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
                                                <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
                                                <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
                                                <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
                                                <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
                                                <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
                                                <option value="" disabled> - States - </option>
                                                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                                                <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                                                <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                                                <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                                                <option value="California">California</option>
                                                <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                                                <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                                                <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                                                <option value="District Of Columbia">District Of Columbia</option>
                                                <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                                                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                                                <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                                                <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                                                <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                                                <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                                                <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                                                <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                                                <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                                                <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                                                <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                                                <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                                                <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                                                <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                                                <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                                                <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                                                <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                                                <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                                                <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                                                <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                                                <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                                                <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                                                <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                                                <option value="New York">New York</option>
                                                <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                                                <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                                                <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                                                <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                                                <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                                                <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                                                <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                                                <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                                                <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                                                <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                                                <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                                                <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                                                <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                                                <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                                                <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                                                <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                                                <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                                                <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option></select>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="input__group input--quarter input__group--zip">
                                            <label for="zip">Postal Code <span class="form__asterisk">*</span></label>
                                            <input class="input__zip" id="zip" name="entry.1010716867" type="text" required="" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="input__row">
                                        <div class="input__group input--half input__group--email">
                                            <legend>Contact</legend>
                                            <label for="first-name">Email <span class="form__asterisk">*</span></label>
                                            <input class="input__email" id="email" name="entry.1265248848" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" required="" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="input__group input--half input__group--phone">
                                            <label for="last-name">Phone Number <span class="form__asterisk">*</span></label>
                                            <input class="input__number" id="number" name="entry.433465949" type="text" required="" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="input__group input__checkbox">
                                        <ul class="checkbox__list">
                                            <li>
                                                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" autocomplete="off">
                                                <label for="checkbox" class="form__notifications"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Receive an SMS notification when you are outbid</label>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                <button class="button__submit is--disabled">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include the relevant markup here? A link is fine for additional context, but shouldn't be the sole resource.

Comment: Please don't link to live code. Your question needs to contain all of the code and context required to find an answer.

Comment: @meagar I've updated to allow contain the button section of my `index.html` The original already had the problem area containing the `scripts.js`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I've updated the original question. The problem click handler is in `scripts.js. And I've now included the form and buttons from my `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying to get value from the label which has `button__form` class which is wrong, You have to get value from the radio button which is inside that label, So try following code for get value other code will be as it is.

```
$('.button__form').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).find("input[type='radio']").val();
});
```

It may help you.

Comment: The only thing that remains unsolved, is how I can make it so that clicking the label will select the input and add the class `is--selected` like I want. It only seems to happen when I actually click the circle. Any thoughts?